# Dynamic approximate nearest neighbor search?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

I'm working on developing an algorithm that uses latent spaces, and the ability to quickly find a point's nearest neighbors in latent space would help dramatically. The following is important for any algorithm I use:

1. Fast (sublinear) retrieval of approximate nearest neighbors (I'm ok with somewhat low accuracy)
2. Fast (sublinear) insertion and deletion of points into the data set. Since points will be able to move in latent space, I need to be able to quickly insert them into their new latent positions.
3. Scales reasonably with the dimensionality of the space--I'll be using O(dozens) of dimensions
4. Easy to implement, or a fast, open-source implementation already exists.

I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00442v2.pdf) which seems like a reasonable approach, but it's fairly recent and only has 1 citation so far, so I was wondering if there was a standard approach to this problem with an implementation already out there.